# Cannot render Excel download using SSRS SDK for PHP

Tags: php, excel, reporting-services

I cannot render an excel file for download correctly using SSRS SDK for PHP.  I can for a CSV, and I can render one for PDF inline.  The contents of produced file is garbage when viewed in EXCEL.  Here is my code:

```
$renderAs = new RenderAsEXCEL();

$result = $ssrs_report->Render2($renderAs,
              PageCountModeEnum::$Estimate,
              $Extension,
              $MimeType,
              $Encoding,
              $Warnings,
              $StreamIds);

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$reportName.".xls\";");
```

I've tried many different MIME Content-Type values.

Answer (score 2):

i'm probably way to late but for anyone else that stumbles on this problem:

the problem is actually that there is a space in front of the first

```
<?php
```

in RenderAsEXCEL.php and there are a few lines after the last

```
?>
```

in  RenderAsPDF.php
remove these white spaces and you will not have to use an ugly ob_clean() workaround

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but I had the same problem and it took me a while to figure it out:

There are more files that contain spaces before or after the php-tags than just the RenderAsEXCEL.php file.

Since the main php file of the SSRS library includes almost all files you need to remove all spaces before and after the php-tags from all files.

After you've done that use this code to download the Excel file.

```
$renderAsExcel = new RenderAsEXCEL();

$result = $ssrsServer->Render2($renderAsExcel,
             PageCountModeEnum::$Estimate,
             $Extension,
             $MimeType,
             $Encoding,
             $Warnings,
             $StreamIds
);

header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"report.xls\"");
header("Content-length: ".(string)(strlen($result)));
header("Expires: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", mktime(date("H")+2, date("i"),date("s"),date("m"), date("d"),date("Y")))." GMT");
header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not used that library, but i have had great results from this one: http://www.bettina-attack.de/jonny/view.php/projects/php_writeexcel/

Built it into many apps without having to think very much about it.